# Addressing virtual machines in the same Azure cloud service

Tags: azure

I'm experimenting multi-VM setup in Azure. Saying it shortly, I'm deploying a single coud service (`my.cloudapp.net`) which is backed by multiple VMs, each offering a subset of specific services (e.g. HTTP/s service is backed by VM1, SMTP is backed by VM2...).

I'm hosting MySQL on a different machine than the web host. The very simple question is: how can I connect to VMb from VMa?

Option 1 is to use public DNS (`my.cloudapp.net`) but this implies setting a firewall forwarding rule, which is what I don't actually want for some services like DB and `LMTP`.

I have successfully addressed the VMs by their internal 100.0.0.0/8 address. Ifconfig output

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:03:FF:41:4A:70  
          inet addr:100.73.0.73  Bcast:100.73.1.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:208209 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:315173 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29385493 (28.0 Mb)  TX bytes:321811574 (306.9 Mb)
```

**Does the internal IP remain same** or does it change at VM reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will remain the same.

The caveat is that if you shut down the VM with StoppedDeallocated option, that will release the internal IP. To overcome this, use the [Static Internal IP feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-private-ip/).